# Camel Quarkus SFTP Idempotent Consumer "this.transactionTemplate is null" error

Tags: quarkus, idempotent, camel-ftp, camel-sql, apache-camel-cdi

I've been developping a Quarkus app with STFP routes, in which I would like to incorporate IdempotentConsumers. The end goal is to deploy multiple instances in my cluster and achieve Distributed Locking.

My setup is as follows:

```xml
<!--pom.xml-->

...
  <properties>
    <quarkus.platform.artifact-id>quarkus-bom</quarkus.platform.artifact-id>
    <quarkus.platform.group-id>io.quarkus.platform</quarkus.platform.group-id>
    <quarkus.platform.version>3.2.10.Final</quarkus.platform.version>

    <compiler-plugin.version>3.11.0</compiler-plugin.version>
    <maven.compiler.release>17</maven.compiler.release>
    <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
    <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.testTarget>${maven.compiler.target}</maven.compiler.testTarget>
    <maven.compiler.testSource>${maven.compiler.source}</maven.compiler.testSource>

    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <groovy-maven-plugin.version>2.1.1</groovy-maven-plugin.version>
    <maven-jar-plugin.version>3.2.0</maven-jar-plugin.version>
    <maven-resources-plugin.version>3.1.0</maven-resources-plugin.version>

    <skipITs>true</skipITs>
    <surefire-plugin.version>3.0.0</surefire-plugin.version>

    <version.lombok>1.18.30</version.lombok>
    <version.ermis.commons>1.6.0</version.ermis.commons>
  </properties>

  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>${quarkus.platform.group-id}</groupId>
        <artifactId>${quarkus.platform.artifact-id}</artifactId>
        <version>${quarkus.platform.version}</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>io.quarkus.platform</groupId>
        <artifactId>quarkus-camel-bom</artifactId>
        <version>${quarkus.platform.version}</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-arc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>jakarta.persistence</groupId>
      <artifactId>jakarta.persistence-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-hibernate-orm</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-jdbc-postgresql</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-liquibase</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!--    Camel Quarkus Core  -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.camel.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>camel-quarkus-bean</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.camel.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>camel-quarkus-ftp</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.camel.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>camel-quarkus-jdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.camel.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>camel-quarkus-kafka</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.camel.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>camel-quarkus-sql</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.camel.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>camel-quarkus-xpath</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!--    Rest and JSON   -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-resteasy-jackson</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!--    Utility -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
      <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
      <version>${version.lombok}</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!--  Smallrye Health  -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-smallrye-health</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-junit5</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
...
```

Following by the attempted configuration for the idempotence repository based on the JdbcCachedMessageIdRepository as found here: [Using Jdbc Based Idempotent Repository](https://camel.apache.org/components/4.4.x/sql-component.html#_using_the_jdbc_based_idempotent_repository)

```java
package com.epav.configuration;

import jakarta.inject.Named;
import jakarta.inject.Singleton;
import org.apache.camel.Configuration;
import org.apache.camel.processor.idempotent.jdbc.JdbcCachedMessageIdRepository;
import org.eclipse.microprofile.config.inject.ConfigProperty;

import javax.sql.DataSource;


@Configuration
public class FtpIdempotentRepositoryConfiguration {

    @ConfigProperty(name = "trader.integration.instance.name")
    String instanceName;

    @Singleton
    DataSource dataSource;

    @Singleton
    @Named(value = "FtpIdempotentRepository")
    public JdbcCachedMessageIdRepository jdbcCachedMessageRepository(){
        JdbcCachedMessageIdRepository repository = new JdbcCachedMessageIdRepository();
        repository.setDataSource(dataSource);
        repository.setProcessorName(instanceName);
        return repository;
    }
}
```

The Route in which I am trying to use the above repository:

```java
import com.intrasoft.configuration.properties.FtpRoutingProperties;
import jakarta.inject.Singleton;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;
import org.apache.camel.processor.idempotent.jdbc.JdbcCachedMessageIdRepository;

@Singleton
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class IncomingRoute extends RouteBuilder {

    private final FtpRoutingProperties ftpRoutingProperties;

    private final JdbcCachedMessageIdRepository jdbcCachedMessageIdRepository;

    @Override
    public void configure() {
        String sftpUrl = String.format("sftp://%s:%s@%s:",
                ftpRoutingProperties.username,
                ftpRoutingProperties.password,
                ftpRoutingProperties.host);

        from(sftpUrl + ftpRoutingProperties.edbInputDir)
                .idempotentConsumer(header("CamelFileAbsolutePath"))
                .idempotentRepository(jdbcCachedMessageIdRepository)
                .completionEager(true)
                .process(CUSTOM_PROCESSOR_NAME)
                .to(sftpUrl + ftpRoutingProperties.successDir)
                .stop();
```

Finally the application properties used are the following:

```
quarkus.banner.enabled=false
quarkus.application.name=custom-app-name
trader.integration.instance.name=${pod.ip:${quarkus.application.name}}

quarkus.http.port=9090

quarkus.log.level=INFO
quarkus.log.console.format=%d{HH:mm:ss} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%e%n

quarkus.devservices.enabled=false
%dev.quarkus.log.category."org.apache.camel".level=ERROR

%dev.quarkus.datasource.db-kind=postgresql
%dev.quarkus.datasource.username=idemp_db
%dev.quarkus.datasource.password=idemp_db
%dev.quarkus.datasource.jdbc.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/idemp_db
%dev.quarkus.hibernate-orm.log.sql=false

quarkus.liquibase.migrate-at-start=true
quarkus.liquibase.change-log=db/master.xml
...
```

And arriving at the crux of the subject.
During initialization after the liquibase migration has completed I am met with the following error:

```
16:10:03 INFO  [liquibase.database] (Quarkus Main Thread) Set default schema name to public
 16:10:03 INFO  [liquibase.executor] (Quarkus Main Thread) Changelog query completed.
16:10:03 INFO  [liquibase.executor] (Quarkus Main Thread) Changelog query completed.
16:10:03 INFO  [liquibase.executor] (Quarkus Main Thread) Changelog query completed.
16:10:03 INFO  [liquibase.lockservice] (Quarkus Main Thread) Successfully acquired change log lock
16:10:04 INFO  [liquibase.changelog] (Quarkus Main Thread) Reading from public.databasechangelog
16:10:04 INFO  [liquibase.executor] (Quarkus Main Thread) Changelog query completed.
Database is up to date, no changesets to execute
16:10:04 INFO  [liquibase.executor] (Quarkus Main Thread) Changelog query completed.
16:10:04 INFO  [liquibase.lockservice] (Quarkus Main Thread) Successfully released change log lock
16:10:07 ERROR [org.apache.camel.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext] (Quarkus Main Thread) Error starting CamelContext (camel-1) due to exception thrown: Failed to start route sftp-incoming-edb-route because of java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionCallback)" because "this.transactionTemplate" is null: org.apache.camel.FailedToStartRouteException: Failed to start route sftp-incoming-route because of java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionCallback)" because "this.transactionTemplate" is null
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.RouteService.warmUp(RouteService.java:122)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.InternalRouteStartupManager.doWarmUpRoutes(InternalRouteStartupManager.java:306)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.InternalRouteStartupManager.safelyStartRouteServices(InternalRouteStartupManager.java:189)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.InternalRouteStartupManager.doStartOrResumeRoutes(InternalRouteStartupManager.java:147)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext.doStartCamel(AbstractCamelContext.java:2827)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext.doStartContext(AbstractCamelContext.java:2509)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext.doStart(AbstractCamelContext.java:2464)
    at org.apache.camel.support.service.BaseService.start(BaseService.java:113)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext.start(AbstractCamelContext.java:2100)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.start(DefaultCamelContext.java:313)
    at org.apache.camel.quarkus.main.CamelMain.doStart(CamelMain.java:94)
    at org.apache.camel.support.service.BaseService.start(BaseService.java:113)
    at org.apache.camel.quarkus.main.CamelMain.startEngine(CamelMain.java:140)
    at org.apache.camel.quarkus.main.CamelMainRuntime.start(CamelMainRuntime.java:49)
    at org.apache.camel.quarkus.core.CamelBootstrapRecorder.start(CamelBootstrapRecorder.java:45)
    at io.quarkus.deployment.steps.CamelBootstrapProcessor$boot173480958.deploy_0(Unknown Source)
    at io.quarkus.deployment.steps.CamelBootstrapProcessor$boot173480958.deploy(Unknown Source)
    at io.quarkus.runner.ApplicationImpl.doStart(Unknown Source)
    at io.quarkus.runtime.Application.start(Application.java:101)
    at io.quarkus.runtime.ApplicationLifecycleManager.run(ApplicationLifecycleManager.java:111)
    at io.quarkus.runtime.Quarkus.run(Quarkus.java:71)
    at io.quarkus.runtime.Quarkus.run(Quarkus.java:44)
    at io.quarkus.runtime.Quarkus.run(Quarkus.java:124)
    at io.quarkus.runner.GeneratedMain.main(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at io.quarkus.runner.bootstrap.StartupActionImpl$1.run(StartupActionImpl.java:104)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:840)
```

Since the database is up, running and available, the connection as well, as indicated from the liquibase logs, I am leaning towards underlying **conflicting dependencies**,
**or** the `camel-quarkus-sql : javax.sql.DataSource` does not initialize properly.

<sub>Note: I am using hibernate as well for some of my entity classes and the entityManagers injected are all resolving and working properly.</sub>

Any help will be greatly appreciated and if anyone has any tips on the distributed locking approach as well, it would be of great importance!

Looking for a solution without an external service / extra pods ( or master "routing" pod ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you use the no-args constructor of `JdbcCachedMessageIdRepository`, which does not set up the `TransactionTemplate`. It should work if you change things as follows.

```
JdbcCachedMessageIdRepository repository = new JdbcCachedMessageIdRepository(dataSource, instanceName);
```

Comment: Yes, using this constructor with 

`@Inject DataSource datasource;` 

works.

Comment: Would you mind elaborating why? 
What is so different in those 2 approaches?

Comment: If you use the no-args constructor then it's expected that you manually set the TransactionTemplate yourself using setTransactionTemplate. Given that's a somewhat niche use case, it's better to use the alternate constructor and get Camel to do the work for you.